# incompatible types in assignment null

Tags: c++, c, null

I Keep getting this error when I try to set the first char in firstname and lastname to a null and return it to a 1.

my code is...

```
int DeregisterStudent(int SID, struct studentdata SRecord[])

{

        int index;

        index = SRecordSearch(SID, MAXRECS, SRecord);
        if(index >= 0)
        {
                SRecord[index].sid = 0;
                SRecord[index].lastname = '\0';
                SRecord[index].firstname = '\0';
                return 1;
        }
        return 0;
}
```

and the error I get is error:incompatible type in assignment 
for these two lines

```
 SRecord[index].lastname = '\0';
 SRecord[index].firstname = '\0';
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not writing to the string correctly, it should be

```
SRecord[index].lastname[0] = '\0';
```

or

```
SRecord[index].lastname = "";
```

depending on how the `struct` was declared. In the second case you might be overwriting a dynamically allocated string pointer, in which case it should be `free()`ed.